# DDEV install - your installed WSL2 distro does not seem to be Ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu, wsl-2, ddev

I'm trying to install DDEV, along with Docker Desktop, on Windows 11 using the instructions provided on [this web page](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/install/ddev-installation).

I have verified that I have an Ubuntu distro set as default: `PS C:\Users\USER> wsl -l -v` produces:

```
NAME, STATE, VERSION

docker-desktop, Running, 2

docker-desktop-data, Running, 2

Ubuntu, Running, 2
```

When I get to the 2nd to last step in the DDEV install  instructions (`Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass`) I get this error message:

> ```
> Your installed WSL2 distro does not seem to be Ubuntu.
> You can certainly use DDEV with WSL2 in another distro, but this script is oriented to Ubuntu.
> ```

Note that `Docker Desktop > Settings > Resources > Enable integration with my default WSL distro` is ticked.

I've got a few years of coding experience, but I'm totally new to Linux / Ubuntu. What do I need to do to get past this error message? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set your "Ubuntu" distro as the default distro.

`wsl --set-default Ubuntu`

Your output of `wsl -l -v` isn't very clear, but it looks like the `docker-desktop` is the default right now.

The default distro in `wsl -l -v` is the one with an asterisk next to it. When you have it right, `wsl` will take you into the distro and `cat /etc/*release*` will indeed show you running Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks!  That worked first time.  Now onto my next install problem.  Its a steep learning curve ;-)

Comment: Lots to learn. Feel free to join us in Discord for support. https://discord.gg/hCZFfAMc5k